# Why ERROR in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have error, please help

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: User::$user_model
>
> Filename: controllers/user.php
>
> Line Number: 15
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\application\controllers\user.php Line:
> 15 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\index.php Line: 292 Function:
> require_once

Line 15 is: `public function get()`

```
public function get()
{
    $this->user_model->get();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't loaded the model yet.

Try changing the `get` method in `User` controller to -

```
public function get()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->user_model->get();
}
```

What I usually do in controllers, which are going to be depedent on that model, and each method would require some method of that model.

```
/*
 * Load the model in the controller's constructor
 */
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::_construct(); //This is important if you're adding a constructor in the Controller, so that it can properly initialize the scope of CI_Controller in itselves
        $this->load->model(array('user_model'));
    }

    public function get() //public here really isn't necessary, but kept it for understanding
    {
        $this->user_model->get();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jana if this answer is helpful to you please accept it.

Comment: Hej Nitesh one more question please .. Why it delete all rows in table it should be delete only 1row here is cod in modules:         public function delete($user_id)
    
        $this->db->delete('user', ['user_id => $user_id']);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
      and in Controllers is:          public function delete($user_id)
    
        $this->load->model('user_model'); 
        $result = $this->user_model->delete($user_id);

Comment: "Quotes" in the array you're supplying in the delete method in the model should be ['user_id' => $user_id]  rather than ['user_id => $user_id']

Comment: Another quick tip @Jana, you should've asked it in another question rather than a comment.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for fast reply ! Best Regards :)

Comment: You're welcome, also if you can accept the answer, well that'll be great.